# Rows value at response is null

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working with php client getting data from Google analytics api. There are a lot of request working ok, but for some google analyticis account i'm getting a null value at [Rows] result even if i have totalResults bigger than 0

As an example:

Rows result is null
   [Rows] =>

but in the total data set it says that there are 67 records.

[totalResults] => 67

These are the dimensions i'm asking for

'ga:fullReferrer', 'ga:browser', 'ga:deviceCategory', 'ga:operatingSystem', 'ga:dateHour', 'ga:country','ga:pagePath'

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail to your question. I have no idea what you're talking about.